# JPA @SqlResultSetMapping not able to handle empty sql result to be mapped to empty POJO - instead an exception is thrown

Tags: java, jpa, orm, eclipselink, jpa-2.1

I'm using JPA 2.1 (Eclipselink vendor) @SqlResultSetMapping to map sql query to none Entity POJO, it **works** when the sql result is not empty, but when the my table is empty [image: empty table with nulls]

the construction of my POJO fails with the exception :

```
 2016-05-30 11:44:17,154 [tp520017379-230] ERROR - Exception [EclipseLink-6177] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.v20151217-774c696): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
    Exception Description: The column result [st_agg] was not found in the results of the query.
    Query: ResultSetMappingQuery(name="nodeStatusAggQuery" sql="select max(status) as st_agg, max(clock_accuracy_health) as cac_agg, max(clock_analysis_health) as can_agg, max(ptp_net_analysis_health) as na_agg from sync_node where ncd_id = ? and type =?")
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-6177] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.v20151217-774c696): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
    Exception Description: The column result [st_agg] was not found in the results of the query.
```

My expectation that an empty result should be handle automatically by JPA for example by calling default constructor of my POJO. i found a workaround to solve the problem by catching the exception, but my **Question** can i make JPA handle empty results automatically ?? or any other suggestions ?

> Code Sample:

```
  public static SyncNodeStatusAggregation getMaxSeverStatusAndHealth(int ncdId, SyncProtocolType type){
    try {
      EntityManager em = ...
      Query aggregateQuery = em.createNamedQuery(SyncNodeDBImpl.NODE_STATUS_AGG_QUERY);
      aggregateQuery.setParameter(1, ncdId);
      aggregateQuery.setParameter(2, type.ordinal());
      return (SyncNodeStatusAggregation) aggregateQuery.getSingleResult();
      //javax.persistence.PersistenceException can be thrown when result is empty, JPA will not be able to map the result to object, thus we handle it be catching the exception
    } catch (PersistenceException e) {
      return new SyncNodeStatusAggregation(SyncNodeStatus.Ok, SyncHealthIndication.na, SyncHealthIndication.na, SyncHealthIndication.na );
    }
  }



@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = SyncNodeDBImpl.RESULT_MAPPING_NAME,
        classes = {
                @ConstructorResult(
                        targetClass = SyncNodeStatusAggregation.class,
                        columns = {
                                @ColumnResult(name = "st_agg"),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "cac_agg"),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "can_agg"),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "na_agg"),
                        }
                )
        }
)
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = SyncNodeDBImpl.NODE_STATUS_AGG_QUERY,
        query = "select max(status) as st_agg, max(clock_accuracy_health) as cac_agg, max(clock_analysis_health) as can_agg, max(ptp_net_analysis_health) as na_agg from sync_node where ncd_id = ?1 and type =?2",
        resultSetMapping =SyncNodeDBImpl.RESULT_MAPPING_NAME
)
```

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 8):

You need to specify the type like this :

`@ColumnResult(name = "na_agg",type="Double.class")`

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is this open bug on Eclipselink. I am using 2.6.3 and am too facing the same - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=484276